# How to get rid of master password in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, authentication, password

Is there way to get rid of the current master password in QGIS 3?

I want to start from scratch with a new master password and new auth. database. When I clear or erase the auth db (even delete `qgis_auth.db` from file-system) the old (forgotten) password is used.

When I "clear cached master password" I get a confirmation message that the master pass has been cleared.

Then I hit "Input master password", but nothing happens (no input dialog). After second attempt I got a "Master password already set" message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After bit o fiddling with it I was able to solve this... The issue was in the checked "Integrate master password with your Password Manager". After unchecking this and erasing auth databese a new master password is requested when i want to add new item to database.