# Set NEW master authentication password not working

Tags: qgis, authentication, password

I've having an issue with the master authentication password. When trying to set a new password it will never let me click "OK".

No combination of upper case/ lower case/ symbols/ number etc. seems to work.

I've tried on version 3.4 Madeira and on 3.5 Coruna and still no success. If possible i'd like to remove the requirement for a password altogether.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this page : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277430/how-to-get-rid-of-master-password-in-qgis-3 ?

Comment: Question is not recent......but I'm facing exactly the same issue....did you solve it?
Thanks

Comment: @SimoneScarpa Question answered below

Answer (score 1):

The dialog is only asking you about a **password** and the confirmation of the **given** password. It's not asking for a **login**. So add twice the **same** string in both fields. The button is disabled because both inputs are not the same.

[image: not the same input]

[image: same input]